# Filter object by proberty value

Tags: javascript

I have an object that contains objects. I want to return a new object that only contains objects that have properties that have a certain value.

```js
const object = {
  a: {prop1: 'abc', prop2: 'def', prop3: 'ghi'},
  b: {prop1: 'jkl', prop2: 'mno', prop3: 'pqr'},
  c: {prop1: 'abc', prop2: 'def', prop3: 'ghi'},
  d: {prop1: 'abc', prop2: 123, prop3: 'ghi'}
};

let group = {};

for (let key in object) {
  if (object[key].prop1 === 'abc') {
    group += object[key];
  }
  console.log(object[key].prop1);
}

console.log(group);
```

Comment: What is the expected output ?

Comment: A new object called  `group` which only contains objects that have a `prop1` value of `abc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+=` operator does not work as you expected with objects.

Try `=` operator like `group[key] = object[key]`.

```js
const object = {
    a: {prop1: 'abc', prop2: 'def', prop3: 'ghi'},
    b: {prop1: 'jkl', prop2: 'mno', prop3: 'pqr'},
    c: {prop1: 'abc', prop2: 'def', prop3: 'ghi'},
    d: {prop1: 'abc', prop2: 123, prop3: 'ghi'}
};

let group = {};

for (let key in object) {
    if (object[key].prop1 === 'abc') {
        group[key] = object[key];
    }
}

console.log(group);
```

Answer (score 0):

You use combinations of `Object.entries` which returns array of object with [[key, value],[key,value],...]. Next, you can `filter` your data based on condition and a the end just keep what format you want using `map`.

You can read more about these below:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries

```js
var object = {
    a: {prop1: 'abc', prop2: 'def', prop3: 'ghi'},
    b: {prop1: 'jkl', prop2: 'mno', prop3: 'pqr'},
    c: {prop1: 'abc', prop2: 'def', prop3: 'ghi'},
    d: {prop1: 'abc', prop2: 123, prop3: 'ghi'}
};

var arr = Object.entries(object);
   
console.log(Object.fromEntries(arr.filter(a=>a[1].prop1==="abc"))); // Keeps your keys
console.log(arr.filter(a=>a[1].prop1==="abc").map(a1=>a1[1])) // Just array of objects
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```js
const object = {
    a: {prop1: 'abc', prop2: 'def', prop3: 'ghi'},
    b: {prop1: 'jkl', prop2: 'mno', prop3: 'pqr'},
    c: {prop1: 'abc', prop2: 'def', prop3: 'ghi'},
    d: {prop1: 'abc', prop2: 123, prop3: 'ghi'}
};

let group = {};

for (let key in object) {
    if (object[key].prop1 === 'abc') {
        group[key] = object[key];
    }
    console.log(object[key]);
}

console.log(group);
```